# Does this behavior seem fishy to anyone else?

Tags: discussion, users

User Didntstormarea51 (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/71040/didntstormarea51) just posted 3 answers to questions that were a few years old in the past 5 hours. This by itself is not too fishy.

The fishy part comes in that on each of those answers, he now has +6 or +7 upvotes on them. I repeat this is in a five hour span and on ancient posts. Certainly not any post that was remotely active and the answers were not even that great to warrant the huge swarm of upvotes.  Also, each of the other answers appear to have been downvoted on heavily (including one of mine, which is how I noticed this).

I was not sure where to go with this so thought I would check here and see if I am being crazy or if this should be pushed to someone to try and investigate?

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for bringing any and all suspicious activity, including unusual voting patterns, to the attention of the moderators. Voting manipulation is absolutely part of our purview, and we work with the Stack Exchange community team to ensure any irregular voting is addressed. Flagging helps us identify affected posts.

I won't comment on any specific situation to avoid disclosing protected information that we're able to see, but we will make sure that any cause for concern is appropriately reviewed either by us or by the StackExchange community team.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed! I just was not sure on the protocol and wanted to make sure I was not missing something.

Comment: Any time you see something that looks Bad (outside the scope of the site's normal mechanisms for enforcing the rules), feel free to drop us a flag and tell us why!

Comment: Thank you for being a communicative and active moderator David ;)